# How to call datasource in OSGI bundle?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2, glassfish, osgi

Is it possible to call `@Datasource` insight OSGI bundle? I configured Connection pool in the Glassfish 3.1.1 Server. I can make queries from simple JSF application.
  This is the source code of the bundles:
http://www.2shared.com/file/H8kNkMrI/SH_27.html

This is the source code that I'm trying to write:

```
package org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.impl;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.api.SessionHandle;

public class SessionHandleImpl implements SessionHandle {

        public String error_Message = null;
        public String error_Database = null;

        /** Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
        @Resource(name="jdbc/Oracle")
        public DataSource ds;

    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Howdy " + name;
    }                      
}
```

When I try to compile the code with Netbeans this error appears:

```
[bundle:bundle]
Bundle org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27:SH_27-impl:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT : Unresolved references to [javax.activation, javax.annotation] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]: [org/DX_57/osgi/SH_27/impl/SessionHandleImpl.class]
Error(s) found in bundle configuration
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary:

SH_27 ............................................. SUCCESS [0.639s]
SH_27-api ......................................... SUCCESS [5.162s]
SH_27-impl ........................................ FAILURE [1.930s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.950s
Finished at: Mon Jan 23 15:59:42 EET 2012
Final Memory: 18M/47M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.6:bundle (default-bundle) on project SH_27-impl: Error(s) found in bundle configuration -> [Help 1]
```

Do you have any idea what I'm missing?

---

**Update**: Bundle plugin is unable to see javax.annotation and javax.activation classes while trying to compute OSGi manifest of my bundle and decide what to package in ther jar. I have to fix the pom.xml. 
This is the source code of the OSGI bundle.

How I must repair the POM file?

---

**Update 2**: This is the full error stack from Netbeans:

http://pastebin.com/R2hnRHVW

And this is the POM file:

http://pastebin.com/Tc1gJiwU

Would you help me to fix the POM file?

Comment: Just a sanity check: Are you sure its supposed to be a `javax.activation.DataSource`?. The comment implies that it should rather be `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you run the framework, for felix it might help if you specify javax.activation (and other packages you need) in bootdelegation packages; Use org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation in framework.properties.

Comment: Is this the proper way to call datasource insight OSGI bundle?  @Inject 
    @OSGiService(true, "(jndi-name=jdbc/Oracle)") 
    DataSource ds;

Comment: Specifying javax.activation in bootdelegation is a very bad idea!

Comment: Besides, @user1103606 cannot even build his code, so it's kind of silly to talk about runtime settings at this stage.